# When I running Python file in cmd its doesn't show the code printing

Tags: python, cmd

[image: Example for running]

when I running python file in cmd its doesn't show the code printing in the cmd but when I running same code in the idle all is works and I see the printing in the shell

the code:

```
import socket
import select

server_socket = socket.socket()

SERVER_IP = '0.0.0.0'
PORT_NUMBER = 9056

server_socket.bind((SERVER_IP, PORT_NUMBER))
server_socket.listen(5)

print("Server is up and running" + "\n" + "The server IP is " + SERVER_IP +
      "\n" + "The port number is " + str(PORT_NUMBER))


open_client_sockets =[]
messages_to_send =[]


def send_waiting_messages(wlist):
    for message in messages_to_send:
        (client_socket, data) = message

        if client_socket in wlist:
            client_socket.send(data.encode())
            messages_to_send.remove(message)

while True:
    rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select([server_socket] + open_client_sockets,open_client_sockets, [])
    for current_socket in rlist:
        if current_socket is server_socket:
            (new_socket, address) = server_socket.accept()
            open_client_sockets.append(new_socket)
        else:
            data = current_socket.recv(1024).decode()
            if data == "":
                open_client_sockets.remove(current_socket)
                print("Connection with client closed.")
            else:
                messages_to_send.append((current_socket, "Hello, " + data))

    send_waiting_messages(wlist)
```

Comment: You need to run the `python` command: `python Ex_12_5.py`

Comment: Could be some problem with cmd not flushing stdout on time